# Symfony2 - How to only show specific elements to ROLE_USER

Tags: security, symfony, twig, roles

I am trying to hide CRUD elements in TWIG so that it only appears for the specified ROLE_USER.

Right now I am using `IS_AUTHENTICATED REMEMBERED` which works against anonymous users but other logged in users are still able to see this.

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
    <li>
        <a href="">
        Create a new entry
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

I want to only show this to the specific `ROLE_USER` that I have set in the access_control in security.yml and the controller. For instance the code above should only be shown to `ROLE_USER1`.

What is the command to do this in Twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is_granted('ROLE_USER1')`

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER1') %}
    <li>
        <a href="">
        Create a new entry
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```